# Remove section from file based on its content

Tags: unix-text-processing

How can I remove the config section that contains `config B2` in the following file using bash? Any quick solution using `sed` or `awk` or similar? The different sections are separated by an empty line if that helps.

Input file:

```
section X
    config A1
    config A2
    config A3

section Y
    config A1
    config B2
    config A3

section Z
    config C1
    config C2
    config A3
```

Expected output file:

```
section X
    option A1
    option A2
    option A3

section Z
    option C1
    option C2
    option C3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="section" } $0 !~ /config B2/ { print RS$0 }' file
```

Set the record separator to "section" in the begin block. Then when the record doesn't contain "config B2", print the record separator followed by the record.